# Mysql Update doesn't update as expected with select

Tags: mysql, replace, updates

I have a large mysql table (20 mil records) where I did an Update using Replace and where.  I ran it and it updated MOST of the records but when I re-run the Select on the table vs the back-up I still have 6 or 7 records that show up vs the 556 that were there before. Just in case I re-ran the Update Statement, it updated 0 records, and then simply changed it from

```
Update TableA set FieldA=Replace(FieldA,'1 ','1st ') where FieldA like '%1 %'
```

to

```
Select FieldA,Replace(FieldA,'1 ','1st ') where FieldA like '$1 %'
```

The select finds the stray 6 records ANd the Replace performs as expected. I am unclear then how the update does not work.

Update: On review I realize I added a Unique Key on the table that *includes* that field among others.  When I first tried to run the Update I got that error, and then I ran as `Update IGNORE`. I thought that meant it would ignore the key and update anyway, does it simply mean that it didn't update the records that would have resulted in a dupe but moved on to the next record due to IGNORE?

Comment: could be you have mode istance of 1 inside the same field

Comment: scaisEdge Not sure what that is sorry (so I doubt it)

Comment: The problem is that without seeing at least 1 sample data it will be difficult for us to tell what may have gone wrong.

Comment: @Shadow Other than the sample query that would be hard. I updated the question to include what MIGHT be relevant info...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mysql documentation on [update command](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html) says:

> With the IGNORE keyword, the update statement does not abort even if errors occur during the update. Rows for which duplicate-key conflicts occur on a unique key value are not updated. Rows updated to values that would cause data conversion errors are updated to the closest valid values instead.

So, yes, the ignore keyword causes the described behaviour. Use `show warnings` command to see the warnings caused by the update ignore statement.